# Как форматировать таблицы в Word, созданные программно?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Здравствуйте. С помощью [такого кода](http://pastebin.com/adALB3xJ) создаю файл .doc и в нем таблицу, в него заношу данные из dataGridView. Как мне сделать все границы невидимыми и добавить перед этой таблицей текстовую строку?

Comment: Вы можете подсмотреть нужные команды, включив режим записи макросов, выполнив нужные операции вручную в Word'е (и потом переведя их с VBA). Ну или более правильный, но долгий путь — поищите документацию на MS Office Automation.

Comment: Можете помочь перевести на C#? Я понятия не имею, как это сделать. Вот какой макрос получился: http://pastebin.com/MHUfm5S8